# Applying a function on to columns in dataframe and returning to values of two new columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, apply

I have the following DF and f(a,b) function:

```
       A        B

0      5       3
1      4       2
2      7       1

f(a,b):
 return (a+b,a-b)
```

I want to a apply f(a,b) on columns **A,B**...
and return **two** values into two new columns df[sum,sub]

```
       A      B       C       D

0      5      3       8       2
1      4      2       6       2
2      7      1       8       6
```

Comment: Did one of the 2 solutions below help? Feel free to accept one if it did (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply` with `axis=1`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [5, 4, 7], "B":[3, 2, 1]})

def f(a,b):
    return (a+b,a-b)

df[["sum", "sub"]] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row["A"], row["B"]), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   A  B  sum  sub
0  5  3    8    2
1  4  2    6    2
2  7  1    8    6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. I strongly recommend you don't use `pd.DataFrame.apply` with a row-wise calculation, as this unnecessarily sidesteps `pandas` vectorisation.

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b, a - b

def foo(df, a, b):
    return f(df[a], df[b])

df['C'], df['D'] = df.pipe(foo, 'A', 'B')

print(df)

   A  B  C  D
0  5  3  8  2
1  4  2  6  2
2  7  1  8  6
```